# CSS grid-template-areas does not change order of elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following snippets of code:

```css
.textreview>.reviewer {
  grid-area: reviewer;
  text-align: center;
}

.textreview>.reviewlogo {
  grid-area: image;
}

.textreview>.rating {
  grid-area: rating;
}

.textreview {
  flex-basis: 250px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "reviewer" "image" "rating";
}
```

```html
<div class="textreview" id="newyorktimes">
  <span class="reviewer">New York Times</span>
  <span class="rating">NYT's Choice</span>
  <img class="reviewlogo" src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="metacriticlogo">
</div>
<div class="textreview" id="bafta">
  <span class="reviewer">BAFTA Awards</span>
  <span class="rating">Best Original Screenplay</span>
  <img class="reviewlogo" src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="metacriticlogo">
</div>
<div class="textreview" id="oscars">
  <span class="reviewer">Academy Award</span>
  <span class="rating">Best Picture</span>
  <img class="reviewlogo" src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="metacriticlogo">
</div>
```

Giving the following result:
[image]

Why does this not put the image in between the title and rating?

Comment: Certainly seems to work fine in a fiddle, maybe you have something else going on https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/r9hxg4yb/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.